# Vectors and Structs in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct

I am trying to make a data tree that holds multiple data types and vectors. What I have so far is shown below:

```
struct VertStruct{
    double X, Y, Z;
};
struct FaceStruct{
    int F1, F2, F3, F4;
};
struct FaceNormalStruct{
    double X, Y, Z;
};
struct LODStruct{
    std::vector<VertStruct> Verts;
    std::vector<FaceStruct> Faces;
    std::vector<FaceNormalStruct> FaceNormals;
};
struct ChunkStruct{
    std::vector<LODStruct> LOD;
};

int main(){

    std::vector<ChunkStruct> Chunk;
    Chunk.resize(100);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Chunk[i].LOD.resize(5);

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            Chunk[i].LOD[j].Verts.resize(36);
            Chunk[i].LOD[j].Faces.resize(25);
            Chunk[i].LOD[j].FaceNormals.resize(25);
        }
    }
return 1;
}
```

Now this compiles fine and is exactly what I want, however, if I try to set a value to something like:

```
int Number = 42;
Chunk[5].LOD[4].Verts[3] = Number;
```

Then I get the following error:

```
 main.cpp|126|error: no match for 'operator=' in 'Chunk.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = ChunkStruct, _Alloc = std::allocator<ChunkStruct>](5u)->ChunkStruct::LOD.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = LODStruct, _Alloc = std::allocator<LODStruct>](4u)->LODStruct::Verts.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = VertStruct, _Alloc = std::allocator<VertStruct>](3u) = Number'|
```

So am I missing something or is what I am attempting to do not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Verts[3]` is of type `VertStruct` and `Number` is an `int` so the assignment is not possible (with the posted code). You could specify one of the members of `VertStruct` as the target of the assignment:

```
Chunk[5].LOD[4].Verts[3].X = Number;
```

If you wanted to be able to assign an `int` to a `VertStruct` you provide an `operator=(int)` (as mentioned already by Luchian) but it *seems* to me it would be quite ambiguous at the call site to what member(s) the `int` value is being assigned to:

```
struct VertStruct
{
    double X, Y, Z;
    VertStruct& operator=(int d)
    {
        X = d; // Or 'Y' or 'Z' or all.
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple I was missing, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 3):

This

```
Chunk[5].LOD[4].Verts[3]
```

is a `VertStruct`, and you cannot assign an integer to it.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing something, and it's not impossible (everything's possible if you can imagine it. That's what being a scientist is all about) :)

`Chunk[5]` returns a `ChunkStruct`.

`Chunk[5].LOD` returns a `std::vector<LODStruct>`.

`Chunk[5].LOD[4]` returns a `LODStruct`.

`Chunk[5].LOD[4].Verts` returns a `std::vector<VertStruct>`.

Finally, `Chunk[5].LOD[4].Verts[3]` returns a `VertStruct`. And you try to assign an `int` to it. Obviously, not gonna work with your code.

To get this to work (this exact syntax), you should overload `operator = (int x)`. Otherwise, assign the `int` to whichever member you want.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning one number which is an `int` into `VertStruct`, which is a `struct` and has 3 fields (X, Y, Z). If you wanted to set X coordinate, do:

```
Chunk[5].LOD[5].Verts[3].X = Number;
```